# How do I create points along the middle of a text character?

Tags: bezier-curves, text-object

I want to automatically place objects along the center of some text, instead of along the edges. Before I can do this I need some points.
The problem is how to avoid manually placing points in the shape of the characters. I'm assuming the way to start is to convert the text to a curve, but that leaves me with a wide, closed curve defining the edges of the text. However, in this case I would like to get a zero-width curve (basically a skeleton) running through the middle of the characters, preferably with control over the spacing between points.

In other words, I want to go from this
[image: The string "Text" in form of paths]
which is what you get after converting to a curve,
to something like this
[image: Vertices overlayed on top of the text, showing the goal result]

Here I've done the work manually, but I would like to automate it somewhat, so it can be applied to any string of characters.

Of course, if solved with curves the text aspect of it is not really relevant; it's a general problem about curves. But if there is some other way to solve it, without using curves, I would still like to know.

Comment: there's a centerline tracer in inkscape, feed a picture and get that skeleton line... not something like that in blender, but a quick way would be to offset the curve to thinner it and then in geometry nodes drop some points on it... wouldn't be perfect though